# History of contentEditable alternatives

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

> Related: [ContentEditable Alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9250272/contenteditable-alternative)

I'm quite sure that there were online WYSIWYG editors and the like before `contentEditable`. I do recall using GDocs and GMail with rich-text features that acted nearly the same as `contentEditable`.

So, I'd like a (preferably technical) history of how such things were designed before `contentEditable` existed. If the history of workarounds is long, you need not explain all the details - just the basic idea so that I can look it up (links appreciated, though), and/or figure it out for myself.

Comment: Why would you want an alternative? It works pretty good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

contentEditable was introduced with Internet Explorer 5.5; yes that long ago. That's a little bit earlier than any GMail, GDocs or anything like that.

Before that IE provided editing capabilities with a custom ActiveX Control (that was used in FrontPage for example)

You can read a [full history at the WHATWG blog](http://blog.whatwg.org/the-road-to-html-5-contenteditable)

Comment: Yes, but that was ONLY IE. The world still used workarounds--some of these are still in use. I don't want a history of contenteditable--I want the (good) methods used to circumvent it, preferably in chronological order. THis sort of stuff won't be documented anywhere, but I feel a programmer from that era would know.

Comment: It was introduced by IE, but then implemented by the rest of the browsers. Why do you think that people used to create a full editor on their own and now no one remembers those editors? WYSIWYG editor have always used contentEditable/designMode (or Java in some case), with new GDocs being the exception.

Comment: Because I remember using such editors in Firefox.. THough IE 5 is pretty long back, maybe FF had that feature anyway. Thanks then.

Comment: And how old do you think that Firefox is? in that blog you can get this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Rich-Text_Editing_in_Mozilla and it states that those features were introduced in Mozilla 1.3, that version was released around 2003 and Firefox 1.0 was released in 2004

Comment: yeah, I realised that--didn't know IE 5.5 was THAT old :P I do remember trying to show off CE on FF--which didn't work, though.. On a school computer, so outdated anyway. Thanks for the link!

Comment: Firefox supported editing via `designMode` on documents for about 5 years before implementing `contenteditable` (buggily) and most editors used it.